# PHP: How do I establish a connection to my SQL Server?

Tags: php, sql-server, windows-authentication

I usually use my SQL Server with SQL Server Management Studio.  When logging in there I use Windows Authentication and do not specify a Username/Password. So the username/password I'm using at the moment is the same I use logging onto my computer. I'm attempting to establish a connection to the server through PHP; however, I get the an error. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

**Code**

```
    $serverName = "MYPCNAME"; 

    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"College", "UID"=>"MYUSERNAME", "PWD"=>"MYPASSWORD");

    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if( $conn ) {
         echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }else{
         echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
```

**Error**

```
Connection could not be established.
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'MYUSERNAME'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'MYUSERNAME'. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'MYUSERNAME'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'MYUSERNAME'. ) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in your SQL Server configuration. You should have a user with SQL Server Authentication instead of Windows Authentication. Here is how https://support.gearhost.com/KB/a453/adding-users-to-mssql-using-sql-server-management-studio.aspx

And you may also want to check if your SQL Server TCP/IP configuration is accessible remotely : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Comment: I read your link and finally led me to the SQL Server error logs which say I'm using an incorrect userid and password mismatch.  Is there any prefix that I should be using on my userid after setting it up in SQL Server?

Comment: @daveomcd no prefix needed for SQL Server Authentication. How about trying to add sql server instance name in `$serverName` such as `MYPCNAME\sqlexpress` (if you use sql express) ? Refer to sqlsrv_connect doc http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

Comment: I don't know that I have a sql server instance... I just know I can connect to it in SQL Server Management Studio by either using "MYPCNAME" or "localhost"

Comment: Ok then. Can you login to SQL Server Management using your newly created SQL Server Auth account?

Comment: Nope, yet it's in the list and looks as if it's configured correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the help, my problem was finally fixed by connecting to the server in SQL Management Studio and then going to Security->Logins, right clicking the user name (not a NT user such as my computer login - but a user I've created) and selecting properties. Then go to Status and make sure "Login" is enabled.  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider switching to SQL Server Authentication which enables you to use a range of accounts.

It seems the login you are using is in-correct; I have used SQL Server in the past, and during registration you should (correct me if i'm wrong) be asked for a password for "sa"

SQLSTATE = 28000 - [Review This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/36df4673-c3ec-4e30-bbdf-69a8690fd28b/)

and tell see if this provides you with a solution?

Also, Review The following link IF you are using Windows Authentication:[Connect to MSSQL Server Using Windows Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296205%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not going to be able to connect to SQL from PHP using Windows authentication, you'll likely need to enable SQL Authentication as well and connect with the SA or other SQL-level account.